# Change font size whenever specific value is entered in a range

Tags: vba, fonts, font-size

My problem is rather simple: I have a range of cells on Excel where the user can enter any value from 3 to 11. I already have a macro that runs whenever a 3 or an 11 is entered on my sheet in the same range. However, I would like to have a second macro that triggers only whenever an 11 is entered, to automatically increase the font size from 11 to 12.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Sub Increase_Character_Size(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Column >= 7 And Target.Column <= 16) Or (Target.Column >= 17 And Target.Column <= 26) And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
    If Target.Value = 11 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Font.Size = 12
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Font.Size = 11
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

However it doesn't seem to have any effect at all.
Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Note: I am pretty new at the Font.Size coding so forgive grotesque mistakes here!

Comment: What is the name of your Sheet, and how is this sub (`Increase_Character_Size`) called?

Comment: Your code works as intended. Put the sub in the Sheet Module and rename it to `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: the sheet is called "Punti" and the sub is included in the sheet's code. The macro is (supposedly) called whenever the value in any column between 7 and 16 or  between 17 and 26 is changed and set to the specific value "11"

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(1,1).Font.Size = 12` works instantly in my Excel. Maybe you are changing a wrong cell or the conditions in the if are not correct?

Are you using a special event to do what you want to do? Something like: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)`?

Comment: Thank you! I appended the code and it worked! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in the Sheet Module, `Worksheet_Change()` event:

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Val(.Value) = 11 And .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column >= 7 And .Column <= 26 Then .Font.Size = 12
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Or append the action to `Worksheet_Change()` if it already has other actions